# Simultaneous Equation Model (SEM): is the following system identified?

Tags: instrumental-variables, endogeneity

$Y_1 = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 Y_2 + \alpha_2 Y_3 +\alpha_3 X_1 + \alpha_4 X_2 + u_1 \quad (1)$

$Y_2 = \beta_0 + \beta_1 Y_3 + \beta_2 X_2 + u_2 \quad (2)$

$Y_3 = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 Y_2 + u_3 \quad (3)$

Suppose the Ys are endogenous in the system above, and the Xs are exogenous. Is each equation over, under or exactly identified?

My thoughts so far:

-Equation number 3 seems to be identified because there is $X_2$ in equation 2 (so it is exactly identified?)

-Equation number 2 is identified because there is $X_1$ in equation 1 which is not in equation 2 (so it is exactly identified?)

-Equation 1 is not identified because there are not at least two variables included in the other equations that can act as IVs for $Y_2$ and $Y_3$.

Any feedback on whether my thinking is correct would be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your subscripts in equations do not quite match the subscripts in the text. For example, I do not see $X_1$ in equation 2 but you claim in the text it is there. (And there are more similar problems.)

Comment: @RichardHardy You are right, sorry. It should be fixed now.